# How to catch null vales and display comment

Tags: sql, oracle11g, null, nvl

I have bascic query:

```
select col1, nvl(col1,to_number(null)) from table1 where colx = :new
```

**UPDATE**

baiscly,
during upload I'm checking if `:new` is inside `table1.colx`.
If yes, I want to display `col1`, if not `null` value (I can't put zero).

Comment: Thanks to the WHERE clause, you will only get rows where `colx = 'abcde'`. Add some sample table data, and the expected result (as well formatted text.)

Comment: got it, but during import I have this comend inside pl/sql, so Im checking each row, so what happed if the where is not meet?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `to_number(null)` is a complicated way of writing `null` and using that as the second argument to `nvl` doesn't make sense because that translates to `nvl(col1, null)` which is exactly the same as simply writing `col1`

Comment: during upload Im checking if value from colx is in table2.coly, if not I want display null value, not "0", col1 is number so Im try to convert null to number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nvl(col1,to_number(null)) will return blank. You can change from that to this:
  nvl(col1,0).

Comment: Im doing it during import file, inside pl/sql, and I want to put col1 or null, when the where is meet

Comment: Then, you can change "to_number(null)" in 'NULL'

Answer (score 0):

When colx = 'abcde' is not present in table1, your query will raise a no_data_found exception. It will not return a result from your query.

You can catch this exception and act upon it.

Answer (score 0):

In your pl/sql, you need to handle the scenario where the result of your query returns 0 rows, which is exception handling:

```
BEGIN
 ...
 select col1 into my_variable from table1 where colx = :new;
 ...
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND then
 <whatever-code-when-there-is-no-data>
 ...
END;
```